# How do I enable haptic feedback in Android 6.0?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, haptic-feedback

I got the OTA Android 6.0 update today for my Nexus 5, but it seems that haptic feedback for the navigation buttons (back, home, app switcher) was disabled by the update. How do I enable it? I can't find anything in the settings for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The setting for this is, confusingly, Sound & notification → Other sounds → Vibrate on touch:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to disable haptic feedback for your Google keyboard, long press on the comma then select the gear icon to open settings. Google Keyboard Settings > Preferences then toggle Vibrate on Key press to the off setting.

Comment: OP wrote: "*it seems that **haptic feedback for the navigation buttons** (back, home, app switcher) was disabled by the update. How do I enable it?*" Anything still unclear?

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down; it exactly answered the question.  Thanks!